# How to output differences between grouped columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
 Product Family   Date     Price Type    Price
 Cereal            2017-11           1     4.99
 Cereal            2017-12           1     4.59
 Cheese            2017-11           1     3.99
 Cheese            2017-12           2     3.99
 Oats              2017-11           3     5.99
 Oats              2018-12           3     5.99
```

The data is grouped by by month. What I want is to output/flag the rows where the price types differ from the previous month, for each product family. 
So in this example, I would want something like this to be returned:

```
  Product Family   Date     Price Type    Price   Flag
  Cheese            2017-11           1     3.99  price type change
  Cheese            2017-12           2     3.99  price type change
```

I was trying to formulate boolean statement and assign it to the column 'Flag' but I kept getting errors and the data wasn't comparing each month for each product family.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Flag']=df.groupby('ProductFamily').PriceType.transform('nunique').gt(1).map({True:'Flag',False:'Not Flag'})
df
Out[59]: 
  ProductFamily     Date  PriceType  Price      Flag
0        Cereal  2017-11          1   4.99  Not Flag
1        Cereal  2017-12          1   4.59  Not Flag
2        Cheese  2017-11          1   3.99      Flag
3        Cheese  2017-12          2   3.99      Flag
4          Oats  2017-11          3   5.99  Not Flag
5          Oats  2018-12          3   5.99  Not Flag
```